# How to work properly with django static files

Tags: python, django, stylesheet

i have a problem with django static files handling.

I am confused about how to use MEDIA_ROOT, STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL

I have a file structure like this(sorry, i dont know how to indent properly :S):

```
static/
    css/
    img/
    js/
```

For example, if I have a .css file in my css dir, how could I reach it?

Comment: The docs pretty much cover each one of those parts in detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are deprecated. Use STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL.

```
STATIC_ROOT = "Absolute path to your static directory" (Example: /home/your_app/static)
STATIC_URL = "/static/" (Could be anything you would like to use)
```

When you want to serve static content pass the context_instance and in your template use,

```
{{STATIC_URL}}/file_path_from_static_directory/
```

EDIT:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, and one thing that i forgot to ask above. Is it necesary to edit the url.py with the path of the static dirs?